# How do I add conditions to a PolicyStatement? I need examples

Tags: java, kotlin, aws-cdk

There are not many example of this area of the CDK period, but in particular the use of this `conditions` method

SDK v1 example:

```kotlin
val listBucket = Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow).withActions(S3Actions.ListObjects).withResources(
    S3BucketResource(bucket)
).withConditions(
    StringCondition(
        StringCondition.StringComparisonType.StringLike,
        S3ConditionFactory.PREFIX_CONDITION_KEY,
        listPrefixConditionKey
    ), StringCondition(
        StringCondition.StringComparisonType.StringEquals, S3ConditionFactory.DELIMITER_CONDITION_KEY, "/"
    )
)
```

CDK v1 approximation:

```kotlin
val listBucket = PolicyStatement.Builder.create()
    .effect(Effect.ALLOW)
    .actions(
        listOf("s3:ListObjects")
    )
    .resources( // these are present for components still using direct s3 access to list and acquire resource content
        listOf(
            "arn:aws:s3:::$bucket"
        )
    )
    .apply {

    }
    .conditions(
        mapOf(
            "StringLike" to mapOf("s3:prefix" to listPrefixConditionKey),
            "StringEquals" to mapOf("s3:delimiter" to "/"),
        )
    )
    .build()
```

Is this correct? I'm porting from SDK v1 to SDK v2 and this was moved into CDK. I'll try to test it, but I really don't want to find out how this works in production.